# Trouble clicking dynamic a tag on timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, history.js, html5-history

I have the following problem which seems easy but I can't figure out what is wrong.

What I want to do is the following:

When I click a link (example: mysite.com/blog/blog-article.html) the href of that link is saved to a variable. In javascript it is blocked and directed to a different url (the main category – mysite.com/blog ). All pages are loaded dynamical.

In this mysite.com/blog there is an a element without a href. I will give the blocked url (that was saved in the variable) to the a element.

```
$('#go-to-next').attr('href',goToUrl);
```

This works fine, but after a timeout I want it to be clicked.

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $('#go-to-next').click();
    },500);
```

But this isn't working. Anybody knows what the problem could be? When I place the timeout script in firebug it works though. So it has to do something with .on(), but stramge enough I can change the href without any problem.

Comment: Calling `.click()` just runs handlers that are bound to the event, it doesn't actually simulate clicking on the link, so it won't run the default action.

Comment: @Barmar Didn't know that. But why is it triggered when I paste the code in Firebug? Is there any way I can simulate a click on a dynamic generated link?

Comment: I don't know why it worked in Firebug. I tried it in Chrome Developer Tools and it didn't work. There's no difference between static and dynamic links in this regard.

Comment: Doesn't my answer below solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = $('#go-to-next').attr('href');
    },500);
```

Calling `.click()` on an anchor doesn't run the default action of following the link, so you have to code that explicitly if it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that isn't going to work. I have multiple kind of #go-to-next links with different classes. Those classes are read and then it's decided how the new url will be displayed. I need to simulate a click event on #go-to-next.

Comment: If the links have event bindings created with `$("#go-to-next").click(function()...)`, then calling `.click()` should execute those bindings. The only thing it doesn't do is run the default handler that just follows the link.